# how to embed fonts in PDFs produced by matplotlib?

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib

I'm using a font called a ttf font called FreeSans on linux with matplotlib. I create my figure as:

```
from matplotlib import rc
plt.rcParams['ps.useafm'] = True
rc('font',**{'family':'sans-serif','sans-serif':['FreeSans']})
plt.rcParams['pdf.fonttype'] = 42
plt.figure()
# plot figure...
plt.savefig("myfig.pdf")
```

When I open it on another program (e.g. illustrator on Mac OS X) then the font does not appear and the default font is used instead, since FreeSans is unavailable.

How can I make it so matplotlib embeds the font in every PDF it produces? I don't mind if the file is larger. Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

I have the same problem when producing pdf with matplotlib.

Interesting if I specify using TrueType in pdf, the font will be embedded:

```
matplotlib.rc('pdf', fonttype=42)
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that it's not doing it already?  From the website:

> matplotlib has excellent text support, including mathematical
>   expressions, truetype support for raster and vector outputs, newline
>   separated text with arbitrary rotations, and unicode support. Because
>   we embed the fonts directly in the output documents, eg for postscript
>   or PDF, what you see on the screen is what you get in the hardcopy.

Back in the day, I used to output a .ps document and use `ps2pdf` with the `-dEmbedAllFonts=true` option.

Comment: But when I open it in illustrator, it tries to find FreeSans. It says the font doesn't exist and offers me to "embed" it, in which case it opens up the PDF using Illustrator's default Myriad Pro font. So it doesn't seem like FreeSans is embedded unless Illustrator is screwing up?

Comment: The definitive thing to do is to get pdffonts from Xpdf and then run it on your pdf.  It will tell you what fonts are embedded.

Comment: @user248237 the font is embedded. However it is not a full set of the font (only the characters used). That's why Illustrator can't use it, because it doesn't exist as a system font and only as a limited charset in the file.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same issue and then realized that if I turn off "text.usetex" with `text.usetex : False` in my mplstyle file; the fonts will be fine.

I have tried with "fonttype=42", but it simply does not work.

I think the issue is that when rendering the texts with LaTeX, the fonts are not properly embedded somehow... I tried to change fonts, but as long as `text.usetex` is set as `True`, I can not get the fonts appropriately embedded.

So, unfortunately, the current solution is to turn off the LaTeX rendering...